# Importing csv file into single column of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, time-series, heidisql

I have googled this a lot, and I have not found anything matching my problem.

I have a lot of Time Series, containing different sensors readings. Each Time Series is stored into a .csv file, so each file contains a single column.

I have to populate this MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE scheme.sensor_readings (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    sensor_id int unsigned not null,
    date_created datetime,
    reading_value double,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES scheme.sensors (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

while the `sensors` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE scheme.sensors ( 
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    sensor_title varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null,
    date_created datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now, I should fill the `reading_value` field with values contained in the above descripted .csv files. An example of this kind of file:

```
START INFO  
Recording Time  *timestamp*
Oil Pressure    dt: 1,000000 sec
STOP INFO   
0,445328    
0,429459    
0,4245  
0,445099    
0,432434    
0,433426    
...
EOF
```

What I need is to design an SQL query in which I populate this table while reading values from a .csv file. 
I cannot figure out how to proceed: should I use some sort of temporary table as a buffer?

I use HeidiSQL as Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of tool you looking for is called an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (Extract, transform, Load).

You can extract data form csv files (among other), transfrom them by adding the info from the sensor db-table (among other), and load it into the sensor_reading db-table.

There are plenty of ETL on the market. Although, I should be agnostic, a free, easy to learn and covering all your future needs, you may start evaluating PDI (Pentaho Data Integrator, nicknamed Kettle). Go [there](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/), download the latest Data Integrator, unzip and press the spoon.bat / spoon.sh. A nice getting started is [there](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/03.+Hello+World+Example). And the StackOverFlow flag `Pentaho Data Integration`, respond usually quite quickly.

Alternatively you may try [Talend](https://www.talend.com/) or [plenty others](https://www.alooma.com/blog/open-source-etl-tools-comparison).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try PDI, while Talend does not support, appearently, MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know. Tell us if you need support for getting started.

Comment: I am now considering NoSQL solutions, particularly Cassandra: does a column-oriented DB need an ETL tool to solve the same issue?

Comment: Although there may be other ways, an ETL certainly does solve this issue, and PDI has a special step build-in for Cassandra.